# Half the largest element in a vector and return the halfs n times

Tags: c++, algorithm

The given problem is:
A multitude of natural numbers "N" is given. Operation half subtracts the largest element of the set, divides it into two equal parts and returns the two resulting numbers to the set. The task is to find the largest number in the set when the half operation is applied "n" times.

Input Format

For each example of the standard input are given: "N" the number of numbers in the set, and the elements of the multiple "n";

Constrains

0<= N <= 100
0<=n <= 2000000

Output:
A fraction or a whole number.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
 
class Fraction{
    
public:
    Fraction(int t) : top(t), bottom(1) {}
    Fraction(int t, int b) : top(t), bottom(b)
    {
        normalize();
    }
    int numerator() const
    {  
        return top;
    }
 
    int denominator() const
    {
        return bottom;
    }
    int compare(const Fraction& right) const
    {
        return numerator() * right.denominator() - denominator() * right.numerator();
    }
private:
    void normalize()
{
    int sign = 1;
    if(top < 0)
    {
        sign = -1;
        top = -top;
    }
    if(bottom < 0)
    {
        sign = -1;
        bottom = -bottom;
    }
    assert(bottom != 0);
    int d = 1;
    if(top > 0) d = gcd(top, bottom);
    top = sign *(top / d);
    bottom = bottom / d;
}
    int gcd(int n, int m)
{
    assert(n > 0 && m > 0);
    while(n!=m)
    {
        if(n < m)
            m -= n;
        else
            n -= m;
    }
    return n;
}
    int top;
    int bottom;
};
 
Fraction operator/(const Fraction& left, const Fraction& right)
{
    Fraction result(left.numerator() * right.denominator(),
    left.denominator() * right.numerator());
    return result;
}
 
bool operator<(const Fraction& left, const Fraction& right)
{
    return left.compare(right) < 0;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Fraction& value)
{
    if(value.denominator() != 1)
        out << value.numerator() << "/" << value.denominator();
    else
        out << value.numerator();
    return out;
}
 
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
 
    int N,n;
    while(cin >> N && cin >> n)
    {
        vector<Fraction> vec;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            vec.push_back(value);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {        
            Fraction temp = *max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()) / 2;
            int maxIndex = distance(vec.begin(), max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()));
            vec[maxIndex] = temp;
            vec.push_back(temp);
        }
        cout << *max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end())<< endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code does work but my problem is its Terminated due to timeout in hackerrank
I've also tried sorting it and tanking the last element but it's even slower than max_element. I am looking for a way to optimize my code or an idea for a completely different approach.

Here is implementation with make_heap as well but it goes through 800 iterations and it geves me timeout (should be able to handle 2000000)

```
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
 
    int N,n;
    while(cin >> N && cin >> n)
    {
        vector<Fraction> vec;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            vec.push_back(value);
        }
        make_heap(vec.begin(),vec.end());
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        { 
            cout << "was here: " << i << endl;
            vec.push_back(vec.front() / 2); push_heap(vec.begin(),vec.end());
            vec.push_back(vec.front() / 2); push_heap(vec.begin(),vec.end());
            pop_heap(vec.begin(),vec.end()); vec.pop_back();
        }
        cout<< vec.front() << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Tried it with priority_queue as well and it also has exactly 736 iterations before it terminates due to timeout

```
int main() {
    int N,n;
    while(cin >> N && cin >> n)
    {
        priority_queue<Fraction> frac;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            frac.push(value);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        { 
            Fraction temp = frac.top() / 2;
            frac.pop();
            frac.push(temp);
            frac.push(temp);
        }
        cout << frac.top() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone is wondering this is the solution:

```
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    
    int N,n;
    while(cin >> N && cin >> n)
    {
        vector<pair<Fraction, int>> vec;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            vec.push_back(make_pair(value,1));
        }
        sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
        while(vec.back().second <= n)
        {
            n -= vec.back().second;
            pair<Fraction,int> temp(vec.back().first / 2, vec.back().second * 2);
            vec.pop_back();
            vec.push_back(temp);
            sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
        }
        cout << vec.back().first << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have anything that speeds in up in the code. When in doubt, try sorting.

Comment: Tried sorting was even worst timewise.

Comment: The idea is not to sort the array completely every time. You may try to use a max-heap.

Comment: @Damien i tried using make_heap but it goes through about 763(should be able to go 2000000) iterations and then gives me timeout so i guess it isn't that fast as well.

Comment: This is a great excuse to learn how to use a profiler.  Figure out where the bottleneck actually is.  At quick glance you don't need to be calling `max_element` twice per iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick that you need is that you don't need to list all the numbers, you just need to have the number and count of how many there are.

That is instead of using a `Fraction`, use a `std::pair<Fraction, int>`.  The key loop becomes the following pseudocode

```
    while (count of top element < n)
    {
        n -= count of top element
        temp = (value of top element / 2, count of top element * 2)
        remove top element
        push temp
    }
```

Currently in each loop iteration you do one step and grow your data structure.  But with this approach, each loop iteration does many steps and the data structure never changes size.

Your worst case situation is if `N = 100` and `n = 2000000`.  Then you wind up having to go through the loop `2000000` times and have a data structure with `2000100` `Fraction` objects in it.

With this improvement, your first 100 times through the loop you do 100 steps, your next 100 times you do 200 steps, your next 100 times you do 400 steps, and so on.  As a result in 100k loops you do (2^k-1) * 100 steps.  So in 1500 loops you have done over 2 million steps, and you still only have 100 pairs of data.

Comment: Genius, I had this idea at the start and tried using a multimap but had had completely forgotten about pair<>. Passed all test cases. Thank you for the help